# Can't use postMessage in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-domain, postmessage

I am trying to open a popup window and pass a message there from a react component, the window opens(`http://localhost:3001`) but the message is not shown. Here is the code to open popup and postMessage to the popup window:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
      console.log('event data', event.data, event.source);
    })
  }, []);

  const onAdd = () => {
    const popup = window.open('http://localhost:3001/auth', 'authWindow','height=500,width=500');
    popup.postMessage('data', 'http://localhost:3001');
  }
```

on that popup window(http://localhost:3001/) open I want to pass a message to my parent window(http://localhost:3000/), here is the code for passing message to parent:

```
  const receiveMessage = (e) => {
    console.log("message event",  e.data);

    e.source.postMessage("message: asasdas", 'http://localhost:3000')
    // if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:3000")
    //   return;
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
  }, [])
```

But this is also giving an error:
`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3000') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3001').`

Answer (score -3):

Use `BroadcastChannel API`. I use it in my projects and find it to be more reliable. I don't see the issues that you encountered.

[Broadcast Channel](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/broadcastchannel)

Comment: ok so how do I communicate between two different domain there?

Comment: Via the `channel` name

Comment: Easier than PostMessages but no Safari or IE support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API